# Acceleration and deceleration an SVG Animation with animateTransform and calcMode spline (easing)

Tags: svg, jquery-animate, transform

I work on SVG-Animation (loader-icon). Everything works fine except the acceleration and deceleration of my circles, I want them to accelerate fast and than slowly stop.

Here my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
 <g>        
        <circle fill="#1FA0DB" cx="30.5" cy="69.5" r="12.5">

            <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                                attributeType="XML"
                                type="translate"
                                dur="1s"
                                values="0,15;22,-5;0,15"
                                calcMode="spline"
                                keySplines="0 0.75 0.25 1"
                                repeatCount="indefinite"
                              />

        </circle>
        <circle fill="#219C8A" cx="57" cy="18" r="7">

            <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                                attributeType="XML"
                                type="translate"
                                dur="1s"
                                values="0,15;-10,42;0,15"
                                repeatCount="indefinite"
                              />
            <animate attributeName="fill" values="#219C8A;#1FA0DB;##219C8A" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </circle>
        <circle fill="#E8C12D" cx="89" cy="52" r="9">

            <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                                attributeType="XML"
                                type="translate"
                                dur="1s"
                                values="0,15;-35,5;0,15"
                                repeatCount="indefinite"
                              />
            <animate attributeName="fill" values="#E8C12D;#1FA0DB;#E8C12D" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </circle>
         <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        attributeType="XML"
                        type="rotate"
                        from="0 50 50"
                        to="360 50 50"
                        dur="10s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
</g>
```

Comment: You've no keyTimes values. here must be one fewer sets of control points than there are ‘keyTimes’. So if you've one keySplines, there must be two keyTimes.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer...still not working:

                                keySplines="0 0.75 0.25 1"
                                keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.25;0"

Comment: 4 values = 1 keySpline. So you need 2 keyTimes each keyTimes value is separated by ; You currently have 5 keyTimes values, you need 2.

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where I'm using `keyTimes`. The number of values for `keyTimes` should be the same as the number of values. The `keyTimes` are going from 0 to 1 and every value is bigger than the last one, since they represent moments in time. I hope it helps.

```css
svg{width:90vh;border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
 <g>        
        <circle fill="#1FA0DB" cx="30.5" cy="69.5" r="12.5">

          <animateTransform attributeType="XML" 
                            attributeName="transform" 
                            type="translate" 
                            dur="2s" 
                            values="0,15;22,-5;0,15"
                            begin="0s" 
                            calcMode="linear" 
                            keyTimes="0; 0.3; 1" 
                            repeatCount="indefinite"/>

        </circle>

</g>  
</svg>
```

I think you can use `keyTimes` only if `calcMode="linear"`